# How do I use express.Router in ts and eslint without error

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have tried to export a controller like below

```
export const IndexController: Router = Router();
```

I get the following error:

```
A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor.eslintnew-cap
```

I have tried to preface this with the 'new' operator and get the following error.

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

The only solution I know of is to add the comment eslint-disable-next-line new-cap but this isn't viable and I don't want to paste this every time I want to export a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `capIsNewExceptions` [option which](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap#options):

> allows specified uppercase-started function names to be called without the new operator.

Put it in your ESLint config with:

```
"eslint new-cap": ["error", { "capIsNewExceptions": ["IndexController"] }]
```

Comment: `'new-cap': ['error', { capIsNewExceptions: 'Router' }],` If in a `.eslint` config file, then would not preface with `"eslint`, right? And, didn't seem to work for me when I did: `['Router']` (in the `[]`).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to mess with the  **eslint**, you can always alias it:

```
import {Request, Response, Router as expressRouter} from "express";

const router = expressRouter();
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable by adding this comment:

```
/* eslint new-cap: ["error", { "capIsNewExceptions": ["Router"] }] */
const routes = express.Router()
```

Comment: Better to put in `.eslint` config file as indicated in other answer 